# How to submit value of InputSelect without selecting another option

Tags: razor, blazor-webassembly

I am making a form to create new products and there is a dropdown that has the default value of "Others" and it shows others

```
<InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="newproduct.P_Category">
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    @foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
        <option value="@category.Name">@category.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newproduct.P_Category)" />
```

[At the start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqDiZ.png)

When I try to submit without changing the value in the inputselect there is an error.

[Submitting without changing value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzCJ0.png)

So is there a way for it to submit without needing to change it? Like it would act as a default value.

[Submitting after selecting another value and selecting back others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZCEK.png)

Using Blazor Webassembly App inside a razor file
Edit:
I know this can be easily fixed just by having an empty default value

```
<InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="newproduct.P_Category">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
        <option value="@category.Name">@category.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newproduct.P_Category)" />
```

But is there any way to just submit the default value without needing to select another option and selecting back the original option?

Edit 2:
This is under an [EditForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editform?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class

Answer (score 0):

I think what is missing is the selected attribute for the option markup. When you select a value, it puts a selected to identify it. Just add the selected to the Default option.

> < option value="Others" selected>Others

Comment: It does make the "Other" selected first regardless of when it is added but when I try to submit without changing anything it still asks me to select an input.